# Delete section from file with pattern in the middle

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I've got many .cfg files for an Icinga instance, and I need to automagically remove each reference to a specific host with a bash script.  Here's an example, where I need remove the host definition for node2:

```
define host{
    use                     nonprod-iblade
    host_name               node1
    address                 node1.mydomain.com
    alias                   88.88.88.88
    }
define host{
    use                     nonprod-iblade
    host_name               node2
    address                 node2.mydomain.com
    alias                   88.88.88.88
    }
define host{
    use                     nonprod-iblade
    host_name               node3
    address                 node3.mydomain.com
    alias                   88.88.88.88
    }
```

I've tried `awk '/define host/ {for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {getline; print}}' filename` but that didn't include the `define host` line, and grepping the reference to the node I'm looking for obviously excludes every other line in that host definition block.  Help?

Answer (score 2):

This solution is pretty automagical:

```
$ awk '!/node2/&&$1{printf "%s}",$0}' RS='}' file
define host{
    use                     nonprod-iblade
    host_name               node1
    address                 node1.mydomain.com
    alias                   88.88.88.88
    }
define host{
    use                     nonprod-iblade
    host_name               node3
    address                 node3.mydomain.com
    alias                   88.88.88.88
    }
```

Comment: I used this on my existing config files with node references I confirmed existed, and got the ole "Event not found" error.

Comment: @TImCarter you are using `csh` right? The shell is interpreting the `!` here you better escape it, try `awk '\!/node2/&&$1{printf "%s}",$0}' RS='}' file` better yet use `bash` :D See here for some more info http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-1

Answer (score 0):

using sed (little bit complicated), remove blank lines

```
$ sed '/define/{x;p;x;}' < filename | sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/node2/d' | sed '/^$/d'
define host{
    use                     nonprod-iblade
    host_name               node1
    address                 node1.mydomain.com
    alias                   88.88.88.88
    }
define host{
    use                     nonprod-iblade
    host_name               node3
    address                 node3.mydomain.com
    alias                   88.88.88.88
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another sed solution:

```
sed -e '/define\s*host/{:next;/}/{/host_name\s*node2/d;b;};N;b next;}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -ne '/define/,/}/H;/}/{x;/node2/\!p;s/.*//;h}' filename
```

this would do

Answer (score 0):

Here is a wacky `grep` solution

```
grep -v -P "`grep -A2 -B2 node2 [file]`" [file]
```

Most probably this is the slowest due to two greps. Can cause issues if you have more than one entry matching `node2`